# Assigning different data types to different instances of a class?

Tags: c#

Taking the following sample:

[image]

I want to add a property to `PreferenceOption` called `DataType` because different instances of `PreferenceOption` could be `bool` or `string` etc.

Is there a way to do this? If yes, how?

I was thinking something like `public ValueType DataType { get; set; }`, but when creating instances of `PreferenceOption` like:

```
PreferenceOption WantsHouse = new PreferenceOption () { PreferenceOption = "Want House?", Weighting = Weighting.Low, Type = bool };
```

This doesn't work, but should give a good idea of what I want to do.

Any suggestions?

EDIT (ANSWER): using the selected answer below, here's what I'm now using (apologies for blurry image!):

```
public enum Weighting { One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten }

public class TenantPropertyPreferenceOption<T>
{
    public T PreferenceOption { get; set; }
    public Weighting Weighting { get; set; }
}

public class TenantPropertyPreferenceOptions
{
    TenantPropertyPreferenceOption<bool> WantsHouse = new TenantPropertyPreferenceOption<bool> () { PreferenceOption = false, Weighting = Weighting.One };
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Code is pretty blur ;) can you just add the code snippet to your question ?

Comment: Your idea ("ValueType DataType") is good. Follow through with it. The code same you showed uses a different approach.

Comment: Overloads? is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generic class;

```
public class PreferenceOption<T>
{
    public T PreferenceOption {get;set;}
    public string PreferenceOptionName {get;set;}
}

PreferenceOption WantsHouse = new PreferenceOption<bool> () { PreferenceOption = true, Weighting = Weighting.Low, PreferenceOptionName ="asd"};

PreferenceOption WantsHouse2 = new PreferenceOption<string> () { PreferenceOption = "this is a string", Weighting = Weighting.Low, PreferenceOptionName="qwe"};
```

Comment: Would this be more efficient than using Type?

Answer (score 1):

use [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx)

```
public Type DataType { get; set; }

DataType = typeof(bool)
```

Comment: Would this be a better option than using a generic class? Can you briefly explain why?

Comment: I think Generic is better, as I commented, this is just another way of doing that if you can't use generic for some reason, but if you can, use generic

Answer (score 1):

You could make the class a [Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

```
PreferenceOption<bool> WantsHouse;
PreferenceOption<string> HouseName;
```